# Run time error 13 on For loop

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface, for-loop

I am trying to use a combobox in my user interface, but if none of the options are good for the user they can type it in but after if they have entered something I want to save it so next time it appears in the list. I have tried the following approach:

```
For i = Range("O3") To Range("O3").End(xlDown)
    If Not i.Value = ComboType.Value Then
        Range("O3").End(xlDown) = ComboType.Value
    End If
Next i
```

But this gives the above error on the first line. I am not very familiar with For loops in VBA so I am hoping somebody can help me.

Comment: That range is the last value in the database that is used to declare what's in the combobox. It should be Range("O3").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0) to be fair so it doesn't overwrite the last value. I am not sure where your error comes from, for me the first row gets highlighted by VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to make the `for-each` loop from `O3` to the last cell with value after `O3`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim myCell  As Range  
    Dim ws      As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worsheets(1)
    With ws
        For Each myCell In .Range("O3", .Range("O3").End(xlDown))
            Debug.Print myCell.Address
        Next myCell    
    End with

End Sub
```

It is a good practise to declare the worksheet as well, because otherwise you will always work with the `ActiveSheet` of the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: So obvious after all! Thank you!

Comment: *because otherwise you will always work with the ActiveSheet* **of the ActiveWorkbook**

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in this case it doesn't matter as my submit button triggers the macro which will always be on the same page.

Comment: @K.Robert - yup, it does not matter in this case. But in general it is a good practise.

Comment: Take care not to modify the range within the `For Each` loop because that will change the end value and mess up the iteration. Unless that is what you want of course! I say this because as that loop is coded, the `.Range.End` is calculated each time.